# Compactly editing Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Reading a .csv and saving it to an array leaves the following array structure in my case:

```
var data = [["abc;def"],["ghi;jkl"], ...]
```

Notice that the strings inside of the wrapped arrays are split using semicolons.
To better work with the data i need to split these strings at their semicolons to achieve the following structure:

```
var data = [["abc", "def"], ["ghi", "jkl"]].
```

Of course i can loop through the array, safe each iteration temporarily and add everything to a new array, but there must be a nicer way of doing this. The approach i had in mind looked like this:

```
var dataFormatted = data.forEach((row :Array<String>)=> {
    return row[0].split(";");
});
```

Which sadly leaves me with "dataFormatted" being undefined after executing.
Is it possible to solve what i am trying to achieve using this approach?

Comment: You probably means `map` instead of `forEach`, which doesn't return anything. You could do it this way if you pushed the array returned by `split` into an accumulator array, but `map` is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let data = [["abc;def"], ["ghi;jkl"]];
let res = data.map(([x]) => x.split(';'));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Using Typescript i get the error for data.map(([x]))... "x implicitly has an any type". Trying to fix it by changing to "x :any" throws the error Binding element 'any' implicitly has an 'any' type". Changing to "data.map((x:any) => x.split(';'));" resolves the errors but leaves the code disfunctional.

Comment: @Jannes I don't get any issues on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQNooEQwEYGMDcUIAZugLoA0q6A5gBYCWeAVgNbBml4BQokATiADOSaHBgA6ALYwADgAo5KAB6kAlEgB8EJeMEzg9MHIDkeY6tXccAewB2g66HHBr1OQMGWgA).

Comment: this answer is valid and the JS code is valid too. TS there is either dumb or you need to `x as string` or somehow cast it but it looks like TS is on you rway instead of helping, and it's uncapable of inferring a basic use case ... I think you have either a very old TS there or you have a very weird configuration for it.

Comment: I had to change to `dataFormatted.value = data.map((x:String[]) => x[0].split(';'));`. Must have something to do with the way my `data` comes back from the .csv reader.